# SQL Server Query to count the number of Negative and Positive values in a column (group by)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you help me with the SQL query of counting the number of negative and positive values in the following table Balance column. Any help is much appreciated.

[Attached the table image for your refeerence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX3fp.png)

I have used the following query but it doesn't combine the results

```
select  ACCT_GROUP + ' account has ' + cast (count(distinct Balance) as nvarchar(20)) + ' Negative Values' from #tmptrueup where Balance<0 group by ACCT_GROUP
union
select  ACCT_GROUP + ' account has ' + cast (count(distinct Balance) as nvarchar(20)) + ' Positive Values' from #tmptrueup where Balance>0 group by ACCT_GROUP
```

Comment: Please edit the post to include sample data in textual format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
select  ACCT_GROUP + ' account has ' + 
        cast (count(case when Balance < 0 then 1 end) as nvarchar(20)) + 
        ' Negative Values and ' +
        cast (count(case when Balance >= 0 then 1 end) as nvarchar(20)) +
         ' positive.'
from #tmptrueup 
group by ACCT_GROUP
```

**Note:** If you want to count *distinct* values then you can use:

```
count(distinct case when Balance < 0 then Balance end)
```

in place of

```
count(case when Balance < 0 then 1 end)
```

and do the same thing for positive values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Giorgos. Its perfect :)

Comment: @Sai Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CASE in group

```
select ACCT_GROUP
, SUM(case when Balance < 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NegativeCount
, SUM(case when Balance >= 0 then 1 else 0 end) as PositiveCount
from #tmptrueup
group by 
    case 
        when Balance < 0 then 1 
        else 0 
    end
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use SUM instead of count? The number of rows won't change based on your case expression. Or drop the else in your case expression so the NULLs won't be counted.